# Incrementing Integer Inside Lines of a Text File

Tags: list, python-3.x, naming

I have large text files with about 6 lines/instances of `3_xcalc_59` in which `59` is some 2-digit integer.

I am looking to increment these values of the text file by 1 every time I run the program.

I know I can increment a value defined in the code, but how can I increment an integer inside a line of text?

I was thinking the first part of the process would involve reading these lines and assigning them to string variables or a list, but I am not sure how to even do that.

I can find the lines by writing `if line.startswith("3_xcalc")` , but I'm not sure how to assign them to a list.

Simply writing

```
for line in open(inputfile, "w"):
    line.startswith("3_xcalc") = listoflinesstartingwith3xcalc
```

Tells me "can't assign to function call", so that doesn't work, but I'm not sure what else to try.

Thank you.